# not able to redo the tikz-uml usecase manual sample

Tags: tikz-uml, metauml

in tikzumlmanual.pdf i found on page 34 a sample of a usecasesystem that i wold like to test. But i can't redo it.

the MWS is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % see geometry.pdf on how to lay out the page. There's lots.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
arrows,
shapes,
chains,
matrix,
positioning,
shapes.multipart,
calc,
scopes}
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{umlsystem}[x=4, fill=red!10]{The system} 
  \umlusecase{use case1}
  \umlusecase[y=-2]{use case2} 
  \umlusecase[y=-4]{use case3}
  \umlusecase[x=4, y=-2, width=1.5cm]{use case4 on 2 lines} 
  \umlusecase[x=6, fill=green!20]{use case5} 
  \umlusecase[x=6, y=-4]{use case6}
\end{umlsystem}

\umlactor{user} 
\umlactor[y=-3]{subuser} 
\umlactor [ x=14, y=-1.5 ] {admin}

\umlinherit{subuser}{user}
\umlassoc{user}{usecase -1}
\umlassoc{subuser}{usecase -2} 
\umlassoc{subuser}{usecase -3} 
\umlassoc{admin}{usecase -5} 
\umlassoc{admin}{usecase -6} 
\umlinherit{usecase -2}{usecase -1} 
\umlVHextend{usecase −5}{usecase -4} 
\umlinclude[name=incl ]{usecase-3}{usecase-4}
\umlnote[x=7, y=-7]{incl -1}{note on include dependency}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz-uml-manual usecase diagram]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What is the actual issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % see geometry.pdf on how to lay out the page. There's lots.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
arrows,
shapes,
chains,
matrix,
positioning,
shapes.multipart,
calc,
scopes}
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlsystem}[x=4, fill=red!10]{The system} 
  \umlusecase[name=case1]{use case1}
  \umlusecase[name=case2,y=-2]{use case2} 
  \umlusecase[name=case3,y=-4]{use case3}
  \umlusecase[name=case4,x=4, y=-2, width=1.5cm]{use case4 on 2 lines} 
  \umlusecase[name=case5,x=6, fill=green!20]{use case5} 
  \umlusecase[name=case6,x=6, y=-4]{use case6}
\end{umlsystem}

\umlactor{user} 
\umlactor[y=-3]{subuser} 
\umlactor[x=14, y=-1.5]{admin}

\umlinherit{subuser}{user}
\umlassoc{user}{case1}
\umlassoc{subuser}{case2} 
\umlassoc{subuser}{case3} 
\umlassoc{admin}{case5} 
\umlassoc{admin}{case6} 
\umlinherit{case2}{case1} 
\umlVHextend{case5}{case4} 
\umlinclude[name=incl]{case3}{case4}
\umlnote[x=7,y=-7]{incl-1}{note on include dependency}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It seems to me that the `tikz-uml` library could use some improvements in at least its documentation.

I tried to just use `incl` in both the `\umlinclude` and `\umlnote` commands but that did not work and it complained about unknown shape. Using `incl-1` actually worked.

```
\umlinclude[name=incl]{case3}{case4}
\umlnote[x=7,y=-7]{incl-1}{note on include dependency}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. 
i don't see the -1 documented anyware so i agree, the documentation should be updated...